# How to stop multiple httpd instance in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, homebrew, apache

I am not well experienced with macOS yet and need some help to understand why there are multiple instances of `httpd` running on my **macOS Catalina 10.15.4**

[image]

**Question:**

If it is not required then how can I stop it all but the only one
which I am using for the development?

### Updated

Result with `App Processes - Hierarchically`

[image]

### Apache Location

Here is my apache location

```
➜  ~ which httpd
/usr/local/bin/httpd
```

### apache files path

```
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: Double click on them & see their parent process.

Comment: *"If it is not required then how can I stop it all but the only one which I am using for the development?"* `killall -9 httpd`.

Comment: @ankii, He says he's using `httpd` for development so using `killall` is not the way to go! That said you'd have to use `sudo` as `httpd` is a **daemon** owned by `root` and e.g. `_www`, and it's just  going to _respawn_. Since he's using it for development the proper thing for him to do is `sudo apachectl stop` for a **gracefully shutdown** and then restart with: `sudo apachectl start`

Comment: @user3439894 exactly, but `httpd` won't show when apache stopped but soon as I start back all `httpd` has shown back.

Comment: pixelngrain, It is normal for multiple occurrences of `httpd` to show when you start **Apache** and the number will vary based on how it's configured and used. Have a look at klanomath's comment and reply to it as I am only running the **Apple** default **Apache** without any modifications.

Comment: @klanomath I am using brew apache. The result I have posted is with `My Processes` See the result in my updated question

Comment: @klanomath do you mean `User` column? If then all are `jatinsoni` no `root`

Comment: @klanomath No, I have set it to `80` here in the httpd.conf `Listen 80`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the default config httpd starts a parent process usually owned by root which binds to port 80 (a port < 1024), opens log files and spawns child processes. The child process(es) serve http requests. Depending on the number of requests and the level of concurrency they are dynamically added and released. It's completely normal to have several httpd processes in the process list.

You can tweak this by modifying several aspects of httpd.

Further reading with an explanation and pros & cons:

- Apache docs: [Apache MPM Common Directives](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mpm_common.html) & [Apache MPM prefork](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/prefork.html)
- Liquidweb: [Apache Performance Tuning: MPM Modules](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-performance-tuning-apache-mpm-modules/)

---

The number of possible child processes in the apache installed by brew (currently Apache/2.4.43; Server MPM: prefork) can be managed in the *Supplemental configuration* chapter of the config file. The relevant item is the *Server-pool management (MPM specific)* part. The number of child processes can be determined in its config file in the *Prefork MPM* section:

1. Modify *Server-pool management (MPM specific)* (~line 488 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf) from

   ```
   # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
   #Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
   ```

   to

   ```
   # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
   Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
   ```
2. Modify the *prefork MPM* config (starting at line 21 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-mpm.conf)

   from the default

   ```
   # prefork MPM
   # StartServers: number of server processes to start
   # MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
   # MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
   # MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
   # MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
   #                         before terminating
   <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
       StartServers             5
       MinSpareServers          5
       MaxSpareServers         10
       MaxRequestWorkers      250
       MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
   </IfModule>
   ```

   Process list:
   [image]

   to e.g.

   ```
   # prefork MPM
   # StartServers: number of server processes to start
   # MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
   # MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
   # MaxRequestWorkers: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
   # MaxConnectionsPerChild: maximum number of connections a server process serves
   #                         before terminating
   <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
       StartServers             1
       MinSpareServers          1
       MaxSpareServers          1
       MaxRequestWorkers      250
       MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
   </IfModule>
   ```

   Process list:
   [image]
3. Restart apache:

   ```
   sudo apachectl -k restart
   ```

---

Speedtest (with `ab -c 100 -n 1000 http://localhost:8080/index.html`):

default prefork MPM config (StartServers/MinSpareServers/MaxSpareServers 5/5/10):

```
    Server Software:        Apache/2.4.43
    Server Hostname:        localhost
    Server Port:            8080

    Document Path:          /index.html
    Document Length:        45 bytes

    Concurrency Level:      100
    Time taken for tests:   1.075 seconds
    Complete requests:      1000
    Failed requests:        0
    Total transferred:      289000 bytes
    HTML transferred:       45000 bytes
    Requests per second:    929.81 [#/sec] (mean)
    Time per request:       107.549 [ms] (mean)
    Time per request:       1.075 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
    Transfer rate:          262.42 [Kbytes/sec] received

    Connection Times (ms)
                  min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
    Connect:        0    3   5.7      1      50
    Processing:     3  103  68.3     82     310
    Waiting:        2  101  67.1     81     309
    Total:         10  106  69.4     83     317

    Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
      50%     83
      66%    116
      75%    150
      80%    180
      90%    216
      95%    225
      98%    260
      99%    307
     100%    317 (longest request)
```

modified prefork MPM config (StartServers/MinSpareServers/MaxSpareServers 1/1/1):

```
    Server Software:        Apache/2.4.43
    Server Hostname:        localhost
    Server Port:            8080

    Document Path:          /index.html
    Document Length:        45 bytes

    Concurrency Level:      100
    Time taken for tests:   1.325 seconds
    Complete requests:      1000
    Failed requests:        0
    Total transferred:      289000 bytes
    HTML transferred:       45000 bytes
    Requests per second:    754.55 [#/sec] (mean)
    Time per request:       132.529 [ms] (mean)
    Time per request:       1.325 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
    Transfer rate:          212.96 [Kbytes/sec] received

    Connection Times (ms)
                  min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
    Connect:        0    4   8.9      1      55
    Processing:    10  125  56.4    116     231
    Waiting:        1  124  56.2    116     231
    Total:         20  129  53.1    119     232

    Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
      50%    119
      66%    136
      75%    170
      80%    186
      90%    214
      95%    221
      98%    229
      99%    231
     100%    232 (longest request)
```

---

This won't work for all apaches. I didn't get this to work with for example MAMP/MAMP Pro's apache!

Comment: OMG, you are a genius. I will update as you said and will get back to you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In **Terminal**, have you tried running:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

After you try stopping `httpd`, then restart it, and see how may occurrences you have.

If in **macOS Catalina**, using the default install of **Apache**, if I run `sudo apachectl start` followed by `pgrep httpd` it will show multiple occurrences of `httpd`, sometimes just two and other times four occurrences.

I actually never noticed it because on my system `httpd` doesn't show up in **Activity Monitor** and why I used `pgrep httpd` from **Terminal**. (Update: I had **Activity Monitor** showing only **My Processes** and changing it to **All Processes** `httpd` now shows.)

**I do not know why there are multiple occurrences of `httpd`, however it seems normal.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I stop apache no `httpd` shown up in the activity monitor. However, when I check in terminal using `pgrep httpd` this time it has shown 11 httpd see this. `➜  ~ pgrep httpd                   
4611
4649
4669
4679
4689
4887
4889
4890
4891
4892
4893` it is very annoying and uncleared to me why is multiple `httpd` running?